# Bash, confusing results for different file tests (test -f)

Tags: file, shell, testing, posix

I am confused in bash by this expression:

```
$ var="" # empty var
$ test -f $var; echo $? # test if such file exists
0 # and this file exists, amazing!
$ test -f ""; echo $? # let's try doing it without var
1 # and all ok
```

I can't understand such bash behaviour, maybe anybody can explain?

Comment: I can confirm that under Centos 6, I can replicate this.

Comment: Not a bug in the shell or test. Just a bug in your expectation :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the empty expansion of `$var` is removed before `test` sees it. You are actually running `test -f` and thus there's only one arg to `test`, namely `-f`. According to POSIX, a single arg like `-f` is true because it is not empty.

From [POSIX test(1) specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html):

```
1 argument:
Exit true (0) if `$1` is not null; otherwise, exit false.
```

There's never a test for a file with an empty file name. Now with an explicit `test -f ""` there are two args and `-f` is recognized as the operator for "test existence of path argument".

Comment: That's cool but for example if I go to a terminal (not in my home directory) and do a `cd ""` bash doesn't complain and doesn't redirect me to my home dir, it just stays where I ran that command. Why does this happen?

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu - Because you provided an empty argument. Having a variable expand to nothing is the same as having no argument at all. Always quote your expansions.

Comment: For `cd` your empty argument does not begin with a `/`, so therefore it's a relative path. To apply a relative path, you concatenate it to the pwd and resolve if necessary. pwd + empty string == pwd, thus this behavior makes sense.

Comment: You must understand the difference between an explicit empty arg like `""` and the result of expansion of an empty variable like your `$var`. The first is passed as an arg to whatever command you run, the second doesn't even become an arg.

Comment: Thanx for answer. I was confused because square brakets (equal to test) works as expected. var=""; [[ -f $var ]]; echo $? - returns 1. So is main rule - all time quote your vars :).

Answer (score 3):

When `var` is empty, `$var` will behave differently when if quoted or not.

```
test -f $var          # <=> test -f       ==>   $? is 0
test -f "$var"        # <=> test -f ""    ==>   $? is 1
```

So this example tells us: we should quote the `$var`.